# как забрать данные с определенного web сайта gem Mechanize

Tags: ruby, gems

Есть сайт https://customer.menziesworld.nl/, с него нужно забрать данные по определенной накладной.

пытаюсь в консоли сделать следующее:

```
  require 'mechanize'
  agent = Mechanize.new
  agent.get('https://customer.menziesworld.nl/')
  form = agent.page.forms.first
  form['ctl00$cpMasterBody$tbAwbPrefix'] = 262
  form['ctl00$cpMasterBody$tbAwbSerial'] = 50426471
  form.submit

  agent.page.search('.dxgvTable')
```

но в ответ получаю `#=> []`.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как решить проблему, сайт на ASP.NET

Так же подойдет решение с эмуляцией браузера, типа Катибара Полтергейст

Comment: C ASP.NET страницами не так просто работать, даже с Mechanizer-ом. Посмотрите, какой запрос отправляет страница серверу при помощи консоли - там более 7000 символов. Фактическим вам их нужно воспроизвести, обычно формируют тело POST-запроса и отправляют методом agent.post.

Comment: Там куча `input[type='hidden']`. Всего отправляется `12` параметров. Парсите страницу, добавляйте параметры и будет вам ответ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Получилось как-то так:

```
require 'mechanize'
  AwbPrefix = 262
  AwbSerial = 50426471

  agent = Mechanize.new
  agent.user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.106 Safari/537.36'

  agent.get('https://customer.menziesworld.nl')

  form = agent.page.forms[0]

  headers = {
      'Host' => 'customer.menziesworld.nl',
      'Connection'      => 'keep-alive',
      'Cache-Control'   => 'max-age=0',
      'Origin'          => 'https://customer.menziesworld.nl',
      'Accept'          => 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
      'Content-Type'    => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      'Referer'         => 'https://customer.menziesworld.nl',
      'Accept-Encoding' => 'gzip, deflate, br',
      'Accept-Language' => 'ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4'
  }

  params = {
      '__EVENTTARGET'     => '',
      '__EVENTARGUMENT'   => '',
      '__VIEWSTATE'       => form.field_with(name: '__VIEWSTATE').value,
      '__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR' => form.field_with(name: '__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR').value,
      'ctl00$cpMasterBody$tbAwbPrefix'    => AwbPrefix,
      'ctl00$cpMasterBody$tbAwbSerial'    => AwbSerial,
      'ctl00$cpMasterBody$btSearch' => 'submit'
  }

  agent.post('https://customer.menziesworld.nl', params, headers)

  agent.page.search('.dxgvTable')
```

Поправьте пожалуйста если что-то можно улучшить.

Comment: Поздравляю с решением задачи! С такими страницами действительно не просто.